# Android: Get data from MySQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, database

I have watched more than 5 hours YouTube tutorials but im simply dont getting how to make this work. There is always something that I dont understand or that with me doesnt work.!

I want to get data from Database and bring it to my Android. I have read this might work with JSON.

Here is the link to my JSON DB export. Is this correct?

```
http://web2page.ch/apps/FruityNumber/recordShow2.php
```

The API I use:
`compileSdkVersion 23`

I'm hoping you could help me out step by step. I'm looking for the simplest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are many ways to get your work done. But I am going with simple one.

1. First of all bring all json data from server side to client side(means app side) by making HTTP request. You can do using android preferred HttpUrlConnection Class. You can visit here for doing this.

http://syntx.io/how-to-send-an-http-request-from-android-using-httpurlconnection/

2. Once you have brought your data on app side. You have to parse that json format data using JSONObject and JSONArray class.For that you have to make a model class.For doing this, you can visit

http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95

I think you should change your json format like this:

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "user": "ero",
            "highscore": "13 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "user": "rick",
            "highscore": "21 Sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "user": "",
            "highscore": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "user": "Stefano",
            "highscore": "alle"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "user": "Test001",
            "highscore": "Test001"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "user": "",
            "highscore": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "user": "Stefano",
            "highscore": "5sek"
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "user": "sven",
            "highscore": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "user": "sven",
            "highscore": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "user": "sven",
            "highscore": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "user": "",
            "highscore": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "18",
            "user": "kiala",
            "highscore": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "user": "kiala",
            "highscore": "angola"
        },
        {
            "id": "20",
            "user": "kiala",
            "highscore": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks pretty relevant and easy to parse. For changing your json format, you can code in your php file.

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$resluts = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
    $tmp["user"] = $row["user"];
    $tmp["highscore"] = $row["highscore"];
    array_push($results["Results"], $tmp);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Thank you, how am I going to change the format? I simply used 

print(json_encode($user_array)).

Comment: i have used your php code but it doesnt work ---> 
http://web2page.ch/apps/FruityNumber/recordShow2.php

`<?PHP
 include "inc_mysql.php";

 $auslesen = "SELECT * FROM FruityNumber";
 
 $sql = mysql_query($auslesen);
 
 $results = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
      $tmp = array();
      $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
      $tmp["user"] = $row["user"];
      $tmp["highscore"] = $row["highscore"];
      array_push($results["Results"], $tmp);
 }
 
 echo json_encode($results);

?>`

I have changed "mysqli_fetch" to "mysql_fetch..."

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to perform this. You can perform a Http request to the server and fetch the results, parse them manually into java objects. Or use a library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) that would save you the work to parse manually and serialize the JSON string to java objects.

But what I would recommend is using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples) an Http client that would let you easily download the JSON data and parse it into a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Retrofit uses coverters for this purpose like Gson, Jackson, Moshi etc.

Using Retrofit is fairly simple,

1. Define an interface (Synchronous or Asynchronous) and define API end-points
2. Build a Retrofit object with the Base URL
3. If performing a synchronous request, retrofit will generate an implementation for your interface and you will have to make sure that you make the request in a background thread
4. If performing asynchronous request, you will need to register a call back through which you will get the response

Finally a POJO class for your response,

```
public class Item {
    public String id;
    public String user;
    public String highscore;
}
```

[Here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is a complete guide on how to use Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use a library like GSON to convert JSON to Java objects.

The way it works you create a model class for example:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Result{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;
@SerializedName("highscore")
@Expose
private String highscore;

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public String getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The user
*/
public String getUser() {
return user;
}

/**
* 
* @param user
* The user
*/
public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The highscore
*/
public String getHighscore() {
return highscore;
}

/**
* 
* @param highscore
* The highscore
*/
public void setHighscore(String highscore) {
this.highscore = highscore;
}

}
```

This is makes it very easy:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Result> results = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Result>>(){}.getType());
```

Example:

```
for(Result res : results){
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + res.getId());
}
```